# Making process survive failure in its thread

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

I'm writing app that has many independant threads. While I'm doing quite low level, dangerous stuff there, threads may fail (SIGSEGV, SIGBUS, SIGFPE) but they should not kill whole process. Is there a way to do it proper way?

Currently I intercept aforementioned signals and in their signal handler then I call pthread_exit(NULL). It seems to work but since pthread_exit is not async-signal-safe function I'm a bit concerned about this solution.

I know that splitting this app into multiple processes would solve the problem but in this case it's not an feasible option.

EDIT: I'm aware of all the Bad Things™ that can happen (I'm experienced in low-level system and kernel programming) due to ignoring SIGSEGV/SIGBUS/SIGFPE, so please try to answer my particular question instead of giving me lessons about reliability.

Comment: Mats Petersson is right, but I'm going to elaborate.  If you need both (1) concurrency and (2) fault isolation then you need to create separate processes.  If the entire address space is shared, then you do not have fault isolation, and nothing you do in the signal handler is going to change that fact.

Comment: Can you expand on your last sentence a bit more? What about multiple processes (e.g., use a process instead of a thread) is not feasible?

Comment: Ok, you are right - I have no fault isolation but I need some fault tolerance - I need just the opposite to the fail-fast property. I can reformulate the question to: how to stop Linux from killing process on thread's SIGSEGV/SIGBUS/SIGFPE and just ignore the context. If pthread_exit is doing some catastrophic things I will hack kernel to change behaviour of SIGSEGV/SIGBUS/SIGFPE.

@jxh: I need smallest possible latency and to share a lot of memory. Processes in such situation would be hard to code and maintain no to mention possible problems with used non-blocking algorithms.

Comment: You can just ignore all of those signals (with `signal()` and `SIG_IGN`), but the behavior of your process is undefined if it occurs and you ignore it. And, debugging that process will be a nightmare, to say the least.

Comment: That's honest answer at least :) but I want to kill offending thread just after signal is received - ignoring is not the solution. BTW. The core of the system is strictly verified so only the unsafe part needs to be debugged what can be done somewhere else.

Comment: Beware that completely ignoring SIGSEGV and other similar faults may lead to undefined behaviour in other places too - for example, after the fault, you may have undefined values in some register, which is now stored somewhere [or used as an address to store something]. Imagine `ptr1 = something_valid; memset(ptr1, 0xc0, 40); ptr2 = some_random_address; memset(ptr2, 0xde, 10000);`, if `some_random_address` is sufficiently invalid that ptr2 doesn't get set, the code may use `ptr1`, and now you have a LARGE chunk of data overwritten with complete garbage.

Comment: Ok but I'm killing thread just after SIGSEGV and other, so the registers "go away" with thread's context, am I right?

Comment: @ŁukaszSowa: You are assuming that whatever caused the raised signal only affects the thread that sees it being raised. But, since memory is shared, the raised signal may be due to inconsistent state introduced in the shared memory area, so that all threads will start behaving non-deterministically (even if they don't actually crash).

Comment: Why not fix the defects?

Comment: @jxh: I will violate my NDA and disclose another detail for you ;). The shared memory is being filled by producer, then chunked and then chunks are given to the threads and they hold sole ownership so it's unlikely that one thread will destroy another thread's memory (still possible - I know).

Comment: @fizzer: Core system can't be stopped one started but 'plugins' are replaceable.

BTW. Guys I'm aware of all problems you mention. I do a lot of low-level system programming including kernel programming so you don't have to convince me but this particular system needs low-latency more than elegance and fault-tolerance is second (but less) important thing.

Comment: @ŁukaszSowa: You have not convinced how a per-process solution would not satisfy your latency requirements. Do you just not like using `mmap()`?

Comment: @jxh: I couldn't find good resources on how mapped (shared) memory go along with:
1) atomic operations
2) memory barriers
3) cache coherence
4) maybe some other things which I forgot for now.
I _suspect_ that mapped (shared) memory works just identically in threads and processes but I cannot confirm this. For ex. if cache coherence is worse (due to slightly bigger memory fingerprint) I will lose some nanos and that's not acceptable. Examining Linux kernel code for all these things is a bit of work, which I can't afford right now.

Comment: @ŁukaszSowa: Shared (mapped) memory without a backing store on disk behaves just like regular memory. Assuming your producer process can call `fork()` to create a worker process when one dies, you do not need a backing store. The worker process can then re-map the chunk it owns to be read-write, and the rest of the shared memory to be read-only, and you've got yourself a nicely isolated process.

Comment: @jxh: are you 100% sure that atomics, barriers and cache work the same in threads and processes with shared memory? If yes, I will reconsider separate processes :)

Comment: @ŁukaszSowa: Yes, if the memory does not have backing store, that's key. If the shared memory is actually a memory mapped file, you have to contend with additonal OS resources that sync the memory to disk.

Comment: @jxh: The only scary part is cache due to its complicated behaviour. No cache lines are lost during processes switching? Thanks for your comments :)

Comment: @ŁukaszSowa: If each process is allocating and accessing a large amount of local memory, then you will see differences in data cache behavior.

Comment: @ŁukaszSowa: If you're worrying about latency, then _don't_ worry about _context switching latency_ - just eliminate it by binding either your threads or your processes to _separate CPU cores_. If you cannot do this, then the "low latency at all cost" arg is somewhat void ...

Comment: @FrankH.: of course I did that. Still cache is a big unknown for me.

Answer (score 1):

The PROPER way to do this is to let the whole process die, and start another one. You don't explain WHY this isn't appropriate, but in essence, that's the only way that is completely safe against various nasty corner cases (which may or may not apply in your situation).

I'm not aware of any method that is 100% safe that doesn't involve letting the whole process. (Note also that sometimes just the act of continuing from these sort of errors are "undefined behaviour" - it doesn't mean that you are definitely going to fall over, just that it MAY be a problem).

It's of course possible that someone knows of some clever trick that works, but I'm pretty certain that the only 100% guaranteed method is to kill the entire process.

Comment: I was kind of afraid of such answer but this system has to survive as long as possible, even with some malfunctions. Said that, splitting app into multiple processes and restarting them may have similar issues as you mentioned, because those processes would have to share almost whole their memory so they will be basically threads (in Linux: threads = processes - memory sharing). So I'm waiting for more 'positive' answers with clever tricks ;)

Comment: This sounds a bit like an XY question tho'. Why are you doing things that may cause faults - it's not "normal" for code to cause faults.

Comment: Without going into details, unsafe code is loaded for doing some experiments  which may have errors which should not kill whole system. The system itself have to be ultra-super-high-low-latency so I cannot afford any sandboxes etc. Please think more about the problem mentioned than why I have such problem.

Comment: But understanding the X side of an XY problem is often helpful in finding alternatives to the Y solution.

Comment: Oh, I thought it actually meant "I don't agree with your answer, it is either incorrect or unclear".

Comment: @MatsPetersson: It could mean that if all downvoters actually took the time to revisit all the questions and answers they downvoted and re-evaluate their decision.

Comment: @ŁukaszSowa per-thread signal handlers attempting to "recover" from crashes in your "unsafe" code parts are pretty much the kind of thing you call a "sandbox". If you cannot strictly fence off the memory these are using, how can you decide/distinguish between "recoverable faults" and "irreconcilable corruption" ? How do you deal with the latency spike resulting from the nonpredictable "recovery" ? Fault tolerancy / Resiliency requires ... fault isolation / failure fencing, and address spaces / process contexts make this easier than failure-handling attempts in thread signal handlers.

Comment: @FrankH.: the core part is sensitive to latency. Any error there is unrecoverable. It's totally different story for the "plugins" - failure there should be tolerated. See discussion above, I said there that plugins operate on "isolated" memory so any corruption there won't affect others.

Comment: @ŁukaszSowa again ... if the "plugins" / "workers" use on "isolated" memory then ... put the data shared between the core of your app and them into shared mem - and `fork`. Otherwise, per-thread signal handlers need complex logic to determine why the signal occurred / whether simple thread exit is sufficient or whether the situation is catastrophically unrecoverable. A lot of knowledge about runtime mem layout of your app goes into those heuristics (to make sure no mem access was made outside the "isolated" mem), and still failure modes exist that'll victimize the "main" part of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Low-latency code design involves a careful "be aware of the system you run on" type of coding *and* deployment. That means, for example, that *standard* IPC mechanisms (say, using SysV `msgsnd`/`msgget` to pass messages between processes, or `pthread_cond_wait`/`pthread_cond_signal` on the PThreads side) as well as *ordinary* locking primitives (adaptive mutexes) are to be considered rather slow ... because they involve something that takes thousands of CPU cycles ... namely, context switches.

Instead, use "hot-hot" handoff mechanisms such as the disruptor pattern - both producers as well as consumers *spin* in tight loops permanently polling a single or at worst a small number of atomically-updated memory locations that say where the next item-to-be-processed is found and/or to mark a processed item complete. Bind all producers / consumers to *separate CPU cores* so that they will *never* context switch.

In this type of usecase, whether you use separate threads (and get the memory sharing implicitly by virtue of all threads sharing the same address space) or separate processes (and get the memory sharing *explicitly* by using shared memory for the data-to-be-processed as well as the queue mgmt "metadata") makes very little difference because TLBs and data caches are "always hot" (you never context switch).

If your "processors" are unstable and/or have no guaranteed completion time, you need to add a "reaper" mechanism anyway to deal with failed / timed out messages, but such garbage collection mechanisms necessarily introduce jitter (latency spikes). That's because you need a system call to determine whether a specific thread or process has exited, and system call latency is a few micros even in best case.

From my point of view, you're trying to mix oil and water here; you're required to use library code not specifically written for use in low-latency deployments / library code not under your control, combined with the requirement to do message dispatch with nanosec latencies. There *is* no way to make e.g. `pthread_cond_signal()` give you nsec latency because it *must* do a system call to wake the target up, and that takes longer.

If your "handler code" relies on the "rich" environment, and a huge amount of "state" is shared between these and the main program ... it sounds a bit like saying "I need to make a steam-driven airplane break the sound barrier"...

Comment: Thank you for low latency lesson but I use all of the techniques you mentioned (including self-made, hand-optimized asm buffer ring a'la disruptor). I don't use any system calls, except for the failure mode to restart thread. As I said before, the worker threads are only consumers which can fail because it won't introduce any latency in workflow, though some work items may be lost.

Comment: @ŁukaszSowa if the "worker" part isn't latency sensitive but is memory-fenced then ... the software-design-wise simplest way of achieving "failure fencing" and recoverability is ... to put the data that needs to be shared between the "core" of your app and the [unreliable] "workers" into shared memory. Then - _fork_ the workers. That way, all you have to care about to be notified about the death of a worker is to have a thread handling `SIGCHLD` - you need no complex heuristics "why has it died". Attempting to "failure handle" with per-thread signal handlers creates more complex program logic.